# lose data in the form when clicking the back button on any browser (Django)

Tags: django

My current application has a form which the user fills and hits the submit button to get the output data. But, I loose all the data which was entered into the form when I click the back button on the browser. All the drop down select list get reset to initial setting.

Is there a way where I can store these inputted values and populate it back when the user hits the back button. I want to avoid the user from entering the values into the from again and again..

Thanks

Comment: Why would they want to go back to the form, once they have submitted it?

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it is to use the Javascript beforeunload event, which occurs when you navigate away from a page, then to store the data in a cookie. When the user comes back, you could check for the cookie's existance and content, and repopulate the fields with that data.

This is my first reply on StackOverflow, so I hope it was helpful! :)